# Eclipse workspace is not refreshing

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, aptana, adt

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 as my text editor and Eclipse for my Android developement. I'm also using Phonegap for the creation of Android specific app dev.

I don't fully understand Eclipse workspaces. I import an existing android project into my Eclipse workspace and when I make changes to the project in Aptana - the changes are not taking effect in eclipse.

Why?

BTW, I'm using the Eclipse version that ships with the ADT Build: v22.0.1-685705.

Comment: did you copy your project into your eclipse workspace ? (that's an option when importing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While importing, "Copy files into Workspace" is checked by default. Make sure to uncheck this. Otherwise Eclipse creates a Copy of your Sources in its workspace directory. 
If This Option is unchecked Eclipse uses the existing files.

Comment: Does this mean I have to delete the project from the workspace and then re-import into Eclipse every time I have made a change?

Comment: No, if you don't import the files into your workspace eclipse uses the files in the specified import location

Comment: I see - is it possible for you to give me a step by step instruction perhaps? In the past I simply did this 1. "File" 2. "Import" 3. Choose "Existing android code into workspace" 3. "Next" 4. I choose my android project from my file location 5. "Copy projects into workspace" and 6. "Finish".

Comment: Yeah, you just have to leave out the Step 5. You have to check that "Copy Project into workspace" is NOT checked.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the highest project, (or the files you're working on in Aptana) and hit F5. Ctrl+A in the project explorer and F5 will refresh all files

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I have already tried F5 and then checked to see if my changes in Aptana were actually updating in Eclipse but no success